# Enable user to draw a circle on Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to Google maps. I would like to simply display Google map and let user choose a point and draw a circle around this point, and than I need to read the center of circle and radius of the circle.
this similer what this page is doing http://www.freemaptools.com/radius-around-point.htm

I went through Google doc https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

and I found it it explain how could I draw a circle from my code. But The difference here I need user to draw the circle and I only need to get the center/radius of the circle.

I guess it must be simple thing, but I'm new to Google maps.

Comment: have you tried this? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools

Comment: and you're going to need this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle

Comment: Is google down? First hit when googling "_Enable user to draw a circle on Google map_" is a detailed guide to exactly that :-)

Comment: the link point to an example where "developer" draw a circle, but I need the user to select circle and draw a circle around it.

Comment: @user836026 the first example proposed by _Jonas Grumann_ is all what you need. It actually points to an exemple where the USER select circle draw tool and draw a circle himself!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example proposed by *Jonas Grumann* is all what you need. It actually points to an exemple where the USER select circle draw tool and draw a circle himself!!

[Drawing tools Exemple](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools)